# Issue - [ONLY IN iOS 11] : The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “DOMAIN.COM”

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, ios11

**This issue happens only in iOS 11** But works fine in other versions
So this question is not a duplicate and need to know what could be the cause

Issues details:

- I am using a 3rd party library(private) & the issue happens in it.
- When we debug the results from the library call we found the following issue log,

> The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to
>   a server that is pretending to be
>   “DOMAIN.com” which
>   could put your confidential information at risk

- But if the issue occurs in **iOS 10** and below it would be fine and would have decided its common issue. But since it occurs only in **iOS 11** I wonder why, 
  Any suggestions or solutions please ?

Comment: are you using a self-signed certificate on your server?

Comment: @holex: Sorry since its 3rd service, currently I am unaware of the particular detail, we have asked the 3rd party service for the possible issue. Till then I am trying to find out the issue.

Comment: @holex: Even after knowing the answer for your question may I know how this can be helpful for deciding why this issue occurs in iOS 11 ONLY ?

Comment: the security level is getting higher and higher in each major iOS versions: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/701/, and the security-level for self-singed certificates are much higher in iOS11 than in prior-iOS versions.

Comment: Againnnnn.. superb, Till now I hoped setting "App Transport Secutiry"->"Allow Arbitary loads" will allow http links, Now it seems lots have been changed in the link you provided, I will checkout the video and update you the status. Thanks for your update @holex